# Round angle delimiters

Tags: symbols, delimiters, relation-symbols

I would like to know whether there is some easy way to create new delimiters. In particular, I'm looking for a kind of "round angle" delimiters. Namely, if we consider '`$\langle$`' and '`$\rangle$`' as the "delimiter versions" of '`$<$`' and '`$>$`'. I would like to have a "delimiter version" of '`$\prec$`' and '`$\succ$`'. Any idea?

Comment: delimiters are a feature of the font you can not make them within TeX.  You could consider drawing something with tikz etc

Comment: I found the symbols in the unicode-math package, however I don't know how to use them as delimiters and with pdflatex

Comment: You can not use normal symbols as delimiters. The font has to have constructed large variants and extension pieces.